# check if same id have determinate condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of products in my table, and each produc can have one or more presentations.

Example, my code A1234 can have presentation 'centimeters', 'meters', 'unity'

```
PrdId   PresId
A1234 | 'CM'
A1234 | 'MT'
A1234 | 'UN'
```

And also, it is possible that each presentation has different attributes

Example

```
PrdId   PresId   ForSales  ForReplacement
A1234 | 'CM'   | N        | S
A1234 | 'MT'   | N        | N
A1234 | 'UN'   | S        | N
```

So, i want to make a query to check if a determinate code, not have the check for the attribute 'For Sales' for example.
Only one presentation can have the check 'For Sales', but can exists many presentations without necessarily having this check.

Could someone suggest me how to do it?

Because if I create a query where I filter by products that the value for the attribute 'For Sales' is N, I am not verifying that it does not exist, I am simply putting as a condition that the presentation is not for sale.

Comment: What is a "determinate code"?  Your question is talking about products and presentations.

Comment: Sorry. Determinate code of product. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Desired output would help.

Comment: de·ter·mi·nate
dəˈtərmənət 
adjective
having exact and discernible limits or form.   Seems to me that all of your "code of products" meet this definition.   I have no idea what you're trying to ask.   Do you have a friend who is a native English-speaker who might be able to help you re-write your question?

Comment: I think just `SELECT PrdID FROM yourtable Where ForSales = 'Y' GROUP BY PrdID HAVING Count(*) <> 1` would do the trick. Essentially any `PrdID` that has 0 or more than 1 'Y'? Your sample data is pretty limited thogh, but if the key of this table `prdid, presid` and I'm reading this correctly, I think that would do the trick.

Comment: @FedericoMartinez do you mean changing the output from N to Not For Sale ? so in your example, `ForSales` column would be `Not For Sale, Not For Sale, Sold` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking whether its either not for sale or doesnt exist. If thats the case, and assuming you have two tables `product` and `attribute`

```
select p.*
from product p
left join attribute a on a.PrdId=p.PrdId and a.PresId=p.PresId
where isnull(a.ForSales,'N')='N'
```

or if you want all products and the forsales column:

```
select p.*, isnull(a.ForSales,'N') as ForSales, isnull(a.ForReplacement,'N') as ForReplacement
from product p
left join attribute a on a.PrdId=p.PrdId and a.PresId=p.PresId
```